# Additional simplifications in sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I am currently trying to figure out a way to add additional simplification rules to sympy, that can be applied automatically. I believe there should be a way to add these using the `Assumptions` module, but I can't figure out how to do this from the documentation, which manly covers simple assumptions such as `is_positive` or `is_real`.

Here are some examples of the kind of assumptions I am dealing with:

- I have some variables`c1,c2,...`, which can only take the value `+1` or `-1`, but no other values. So whenever I have any `c1**2` or similar in any term, I can just drop this.
- There is a set of variables `w1,w2,w3,...`, which in sum can never be greater than another variable`d`. So whenever I have an expression like `d-w1-w2` I know this must be positive.

Of course I can always take any expression and then later apply simplifications on the expression trees, which match these assumptions. However, this is really complicated and leads to sympy functions taking more time than they should. E.g. I am calculating the determinant of a matrix involving these variables, and the resulting expression (before simplification) is very long. After additional simplifications, it only has very few terms. So it would be great if sympy could already perform these simplifications during calculation of the determinant to speed up everything. Similarly, I have to calculate a lot of inverses of matrices involving these variables and it would be nice to have the simplifications during calculation of the inverse.

Is there any tutorial on how to add such additional simplification rules?

Comment: There is no such tutorial. The Assumptions module is not integrated with the rest of SymPy; in particular it has no effect on simplifications. Can't say more without a [mcve]